# How to optimize background-image similar to <picture> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, optimization

I make a website and download speed is extremely important, especially for mobile devices.
How can I optimize the loading of images as we do with  tag, but for background-image in 'style' attribute?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? How are you optimizing things with the picture tag?

Comment: @VictoriaRuiz I meant loading different pictures for different sizes of screen

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript..

get width/height of screen with java script, put it in variable and do if statements and then set styling of element.

```
var width = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;

if(width>700){
document.getElementById("id").style.background="url('image.png')";
}
```

u add as many if statements as you need, similar to @meda queries